# download success but video don't shows in IOS cordova

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

while using [cordova plugin file transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer), download file successfully, it didn't shows anywhere, code added below:

```
var onGetDirectorySuccess = function(fileEntry) {
    downloadpostnow(fileEntry, 'http://50.63.14.130/Images/OrderProof/Plugd7a09191-7cdd-4f21-babd-041e3f914ebb.MOV');
}

var onGetDirectoryFail = function(error) {
    showError("There is an error while processing your download.",0);
    return false;
}

var onRequestFileSystemSuccess = function(fileSystem) {
    var entry=fileSystem.root;
    entry.getDirectory("plug", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
}

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null);

function downloadpostnow(fileEntry, uri){
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
var uri = encodeURI(uri);
var uriname = uri.split("/");
uriname = uriname[uriname.length-1];
fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL+uriname,
    function (entry) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(entry));
        //showError("Download Completed.",1);
        fileTransfer.abort();
    },
    function (error) {
        fileTransfer.abort();
        //showError("There is an error while downloading your post.",0);
        return false;
    },
    true,
    {/**/}
);
}
```

using this function, file download complete, it wouldn't show in IOS

Comment: it is stored in document directory . can share path of that downloaded video ?  you can get using fileURL .

Comment: file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/some_id/Documents/plug/Plugd7a09191-7cdd-4f21-babd-041e3f914ebb.MOV

Comment: Can you clarify where exactly in iOS do you want to see the video?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show downloaded video .

Here is what I do:

1. (once!) Make sure all hidden files are visible on your Mac:
   In terminal window run:
   defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
2. While in Xcode, open Organizer -> Devices, find your iPhone and from their find your application in Applications folder.
3. At the bottom click Download and download the application to your desktop (anywhere)
4. Open Finder, navigate to the downloaded file, right click on it and select Show Package Contents. The view will change to standard finder view with open files in that app. (Follow url file path)
5. Go to the Documents folder, find your *.MOV file, right click on it and choose Open With -> Other.

Comment: thanks for replay, but i means the video is not show in device, like : in photos

Comment: you need to write video to gallery .

Comment: try to search for UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum in google.